# csh script - Redirect block of commands to file

Tags: shell, csh

I searched in Google a lot, but couldn't find.

I have a csh script to create a file. There are many echo commands which I want to redirect to a file.

I don't want to redirect to the file in each echo command. Is there any way we can make it block and write to file in single command.

Here is my script

**myscript.sh**

```
#!/bin/csh

set file_dir="/home/user/somedir"
set output_file="/home/user/outputdir/details.txt"

#Block Starts Here
echo "Write Something"
echo "Some content goes here"
echo "Dir : $file_dir"
echo "Destination : $output_file"
echo "Generated at : `date`"

foreach file ( `ls $file_dir` )
    set file_name="$file_dir""/""$file"
    set cksum=`cksum $file_name`
    set md5=`md5sum $file_name`
    set checksum=`echo $cksum | awk -F' ' '{$NF=""; print $0}'`
    set md5sum=`echo $md5 | awk -F' ' '{$NF=""; print $0}'`
    echo "#### START ####"
    echo "File Name : $file"
    echo "Checksum : $checksum"
    echo "MD5Sum : $md5sum"
    echo "#### END ####"
end 
# Block Ends Here
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. foreach - for csh - is internal command, so it can't be redirected.

This is what I suggest:

*myscript.csh*

```
#!/bin/csh

set file_dir="/tmp"
set output_file="/tmp/details.txt"

#Block Starts Here
echo "Write Something"
echo "Some content goes here"
echo "Dir : $file_dir"
echo "Destination : $output_file"
echo "Generated at : `date`"

foreach file ( `ls $file_dir` )
    set file_name="$file_dir""/""$file"
    set cksum=`cksum $file_name`
    set md5=`md5sum $file_name`
    set checksum=`echo $cksum | awk -F' ' '{$NF=""; print $0}'`
    set md5sum=`echo $md5 | awk -F' ' '{$NF=""; print $0}'`
    csh logger.csh $file $checksum $md5sum >> $output_file
end
# Block Ends Here
```

Then add the following

*logger.csh*

```
#!/bin/csh
echo "#### START ####"
echo "File Name : $1"
echo "Checksum : $2"
echo "MD5Sum : $3"
echo "#### END ####"
```

If you want to redirect errors too, include whole foreach in another .csh script then redirect output to /dev/null

---

Alternatively:

*myscript.csh*

```
#!/bin/csh
set file_dir="/tmp"
set output_file="/tmp/details.txt"
csh block.csh $file_dir $output_file > $output_file >& /dev/null
```

*block.csh*

```
#!/bin/csh
set file_dir=$1
set output_file=$2
#Block Starts Here
echo "Write Something"
echo "Some content goes here"
echo "Dir : $file_dir"
echo "Destination : $output_file"
echo "Generated at : `date`"

foreach file ( `ls $file_dir` )
    set file_name="$file_dir""/""$file"
    set cksum=`cksum $file_name`
    set md5=`md5sum $file_name`
    set checksum=`echo $cksum | awk -F' ' '{$NF=""; print $0}'`
    set md5sum=`echo $md5 | awk -F' ' '{$NF=""; print $0}'`
    echo "#### START ####"
    echo "File Name : $file"
    echo "Checksum : $checksum"
    echo "MD5Sum : $md5sum"
    echo "#### END ####"
end
# Block Ends Here
```